# QTreeWidget alternate row color setting

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to set color to alternate row in the treewidget I did with

```
setAlternatingRowColors(1);
QPalette p = palette();
p.setColor( QPalette::AlternateBase, QColor(226, 237, 253) );
setPalette(p);
```

But here after every single click the color is setting to the row below the already set row or the color setting is toggling between rows. I want it to be set constant to particular row.  Means first if 2nd row is setting color then after single click the color set is going to 3rd row. I want it to be in 2nd row only

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the model to do this and return the approrpriate color for the background in your model. When `data(const QModelIndex& index, int role)` is called the model object for the view (or `QTreeWidget` in your case), one of the values of `role` will be `Qt::BackgroundRole`. Something like the following would do what you want:

```
QVariant SomeModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role)
{
    switch(role)
    {
    // other role handling code here. below is the except for handling BackgroundRole
    case Qt::BackgroundRole:
        if (0 == index.row() % 2)
            return QColor(226, 237, 253);
        else
            return Qt::white;
    break;
    }
}
```